# How to combine AND and OR operators in a if statement?

Tags: php

I have the following strings that contains parts of a domain as string.

```
$scheme="http";
$host="example.com";
$filename="demo.php";
$request_uri="/folder/demo.php";
```

$host and $filename variables one of them is optional. 
I am using the following code to check if strings contain the correct value,  print the successful messege ,else print the error message

```
if($scheme ="http" OR $host ="example.com" & $filename ="demo.php" & $request_uri ="/folder/demo.php")
{echo "Sucessful";}
else
{echo "Fail";}
```

It doesnt work as expected, and I am getting "Successful" everytime . I think the AND oprator is being ignored in the if statement.

Any Idea?

Comment: `&` is a bit-wise AND. You probably need to use `&&`.

Comment: `=` is an assignment. You probably need to use `==`

Comment: `&` is a bit-wise operator. `OR` has a lower precedence than `||` just as `AND` has a lower precedence than `&&`. Also `|` is bitwise. May wanna read [this](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.operators.php). Not to mention `=` is assignment.

Comment: If you are using && and & and | and ||.

The bitwise & has higher precedence followed by | and && and ||.

When comparing, you need to know which has higher precedence and place parenthesis accordingly.

    a || b && c

would be executed as such
b && c and the result is || with a.

Which is why you would have 

    (a || b ) && c
And the = is for assigning, not comparing.

Comment: My 2 cents : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: `https` is not valid `scheme`? It might be easier to read a regex processing this rather than splitting the bits then comparing; not sure where the data comes from though so maybe not...

Answer (score 3):

```
if( $scheme == "http"
    && ($host == "example.com" || $filename == "demo.php")
    && $request_uri == "/folder/demo.php"
) {
    echo "Sucessful";
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

`&&` and `||` are PHP's operators for AND and OR.  Also `=` assigns a value to a variable, not comparing for equality.  Use `==` or `===` for comparing.

Also, it seemed that your written statement of requirements did not match your code ... so I changed the logic a little and added () to group the logic.  From the written it sounds like the $scheme AND $request_uri test were required and either $host or $filename were required.  Your code didn't seem to match that.  If I misunderstood your written requirment, change the &&  and || and () around as you require.  Note that breaking long boolean expressions into multiple lines and the use of () to group logic often helps with getting it right.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok, sir. I've added comments.  Didn't think I need to completely spell it out.

Comment: You should completely spell it out because a newbie may find your answer and still not understand what you did or why you did it that way. You still haven't explained about grouping the OR statements, you just explained the operators. Comments above also mention operator precedence, which is very important.

Comment: Agree.  Will do in the future.  BTW, I'm typing my answer and comments while pretending to participate in a very boring meeting at work which explains my brevity :)

Comment: In addition, you have not followed the OP's logic. Look at where the first OR is. +1 for answering in a boring meeting :)

Comment: Thanks, Jay.  That's more that I left unexplained.  Answer has been updated.